# Infragistics WebHierarchicalDataGrid Unable to determine when a child row is selected and then how to get the data that is selected

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, infragistics, webgrid

I have dragged a WebHierarchicalDataGrid to the page and have told it not to autogenerate bands or autogenerate columns.  Enable Ajax is unchecked.  Via codebehind, I manually created the columns on the grid for both the parent and child tables.  I have double clicked on RowSelectionEvent to test to see if the event ever fires.  When I select a row from a child table, the event never fires.  Is there a child row selection event that I am not aware of?  If not can someone show me the correct way to get field data from a child row that was selected.  I have been working on this for several days and I am pretty frustrated that there seems to be no easy way to accomplish this task.  Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Here is my code:

protected void WebHierarchicalDataGrid1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string physicianNPI;
            physicianNPI = Session.Contents["physicianNPI"].ToString();

```
        // Create Parent Row - Patient Table 
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.DataSource = WebHierarchicalDataSource1;
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.DataKeyFields = "MPI";
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("MPI", "MPI"));
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("Fname", "Fname"));
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("Lname", "Lname"));
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("DOB", "DOB"));
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("Address", "Address"));
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("SSN", "SSN"));

        // Create Child Rows - Referral Table
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Bands.Add(CreateNewBand("LinqDataSource1Referrals_DefaultView", "LinqDataSource1Referrals_DefaultView", "REFGUID"));
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Bands["LinqDataSource1Referrals_DefaultView"].Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("MPI", "MPI"));
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Bands["LinqDataSource1Referrals_DefaultView"].Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("RefDate", "Refferal Date"));
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Bands["LinqDataSource1Referrals_DefaultView"].Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("RefReason", "Referral Reason"));
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Bands["LinqDataSource1Referrals_DefaultView"].Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("Insurance", "Insurance"));
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Bands["LinqDataSource1Referrals_DefaultView"].Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("AcceptDate", "Accept Date"));
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Bands["LinqDataSource1Referrals_DefaultView"].Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("DenyDate", "Deny Date"));

        // Create Child Rows - UpLoad Table
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Bands.Add(CreateNewBand("LinqDataSource1UpLoad_DefaultView", "LinqDataSource1UpLoad_DefaultView", "UploadIndex"));
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Bands["LinqDataSource1UpLoad_DefaultView"].Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("MPI", "MPI"));
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Bands["LinqDataSource1UpLoad_DefaultView"].Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("FileDate", "File Date"));
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Bands["LinqDataSource1UpLoad_DefaultView"].Columns.Add(CreateNewBoundDataField("FileType", "File Type"));



        this.WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Columns[0].Hidden = true;
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Bands[0].Columns[0].Hidden = true;
        WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.Bands[1].Columns[0].Hidden = true;



    }



    public static BoundDataField CreateNewBoundDataField(string columnName, string headerText)
    {
        BoundDataField boundDataField = new BoundDataField();
        boundDataField.DataFieldName = columnName;
        boundDataField.Key = columnName;
        boundDataField.Header.Text = headerText;

        return boundDataField;
    }

    public static Band CreateNewBand(string key, string dataMember, string dataKeyField)
    {
        Band band = new Band();
        band.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        band.Key = key;
        band.DataMember = dataMember;
        band.DataKeyFields = dataKeyField;
        return band;
    }

    protected void WebHierarchicalDataGrid1_InitializeBand(object sender, BandEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.Band.Columns)
        {

            if (item is BoundDataField)
            {
                BoundDataField field = item as BoundDataField;
                string fieldname;
                fieldname = field.ToString();


        // Set the column width for each field displayed in a grid.


                if (fieldname.Contains("Fname"))
                {
                    field.Width = Unit.Parse("75");
                }

                if (fieldname.Contains("Lname"))
                {
                    field.Width = Unit.Parse("75");
                }

                if (fieldname.Contains("Address"))
                {
                    field.Width = Unit.Parse("190");
                }

                if (fieldname.Contains("DOB"))
                {
                    field.Width = Unit.Parse("75");
                }

                if (fieldname.Contains("SSN"))
                {
                    field.Width = Unit.Parse("75");
                }

                if (fieldname.Contains("FileDate"))
                {
                    field.Width = Unit.Parse("75");
                }
                if (fieldname.Contains("FileType"))
                {
                    field.Width = Unit.Parse("100");
                }


            }
        }
```

Making some progress.  The row selection event is now firing when I select the second child row.  I changed the following properties on the WebHierarchicalDataGrid.

WebHierarchicalDataGrid1 Properties -> Selection -> AutoPostBackFlags -> RowSelectionChanged -> True (it was originally false)

I also made these changes.  Not sure if they made the difference though.

Properties -> RowSelectorClientEvents -> RowSelectorClicked -> WebHierarchicalDataGrid1_Selection_RowSelectionChanged

Properties -> RowSelectorClientEvents-> RowSelectorClicking -> WebHierarchicalDataGrid1_Selection_RowSelectionChanged

Here is the GRID ASP.net Code:

```
        <ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid ID="WebHierarchicalDataGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateBands="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableAjax="False" Height="350px" style="z-index: 1; left: 0px; top: 30px; position: absolute; height: 352px; width: 402px" Width="875px" OnInit="WebHierarchicalDataGrid1_Init" OnInitializeBand="WebHierarchicalDataGrid1_InitializeBand" OnRowSelectionChanged="WebHierarchicalDataGrid1_RowSelectionChanged" OnRowIslandDataBound="WebHierarchicalDataGrid1_RowIslandDataBound" >
            <Behaviors>
                <ig:Selection RowSelectType="Single">
                    <SelectionClientEvents RowSelectionChanged="WebHierarchicalDataGrid1_Selection_RowSelectionChanged" />
                    <AutoPostBackFlags RowSelectionChanged="True" />
                </ig:Selection>
                <ig:RowSelectors EnableInheritance="True">
                    <RowSelectorClientEvents RowSelectorClicked="WebHierarchicalDataGrid1_Selection_RowSelectionChanged" RowSelectorClicking="WebHierarchicalDataGrid1_Selection_RowSelectionChanged" />
                </ig:RowSelectors>
            </Behaviors>
        </ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid>
        <igtxt:WebImageButton ID="btnViewChartData" runat="server" OnClick="btnViewChartData_Click" style="z-index: 1; left: 417px; top: 438px; position: absolute" Text="View Chart Data" UseBrowserDefaults="False">
            <Appearance>
                <ButtonStyle BackColor="Control" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False">
                    <BorderDetails ColorBottom="112, 112, 112" ColorLeft="240, 240, 240" ColorRight="112, 112, 112" ColorTop="240, 240, 240" />
                </ButtonStyle>
                <InnerBorder ColorBottom="160, 160, 160" ColorLeft="White" ColorRight="160, 160, 160" ColorTop="White" StyleBottom="Solid" StyleLeft="Solid" StyleRight="Solid" StyleTop="Solid" WidthBottom="1px" WidthLeft="1px" WidthRight="1px" WidthTop="1px" />
            </Appearance>
            <FocusAppearance>
                <ButtonStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False">
                    <BorderDetails ColorBottom="Black" ColorLeft="Black" ColorRight="Black" ColorTop="Black" />
                </ButtonStyle>
                <InnerBorder ColorBottom="224, 224, 224" ColorLeft="246, 246, 246" ColorRight="224, 224, 224" ColorTop="246, 246, 246" StyleBottom="Ridge" StyleLeft="Solid" StyleRight="Ridge" StyleTop="Solid" WidthBottom="2px" WidthLeft="2px" WidthRight="2px" WidthTop="2px" />
            </FocusAppearance>
            <HoverAppearance>
                <ButtonStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False">
                </ButtonStyle>
            </HoverAppearance>
            <PressedAppearance>
                <ButtonStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False">
                    <BorderDetails ColorBottom="Black" ColorLeft="Black" ColorRight="Black" ColorTop="Black" />
                </ButtonStyle>
                <InnerBorder ColorBottom="246, 246, 246" ColorLeft="112, 112, 112" ColorRight="246, 246, 246" ColorTop="112, 112, 112" StyleBottom="Solid" StyleLeft="Solid" StyleRight="Solid" StyleTop="Solid" WidthBottom="2px" WidthLeft="2px" WidthRight="2px" WidthTop="2px" />
            </PressedAppearance>
            <DisabledAppearance>
                <ButtonStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False">
                </ButtonStyle>
            </DisabledAppearance>
        </igtxt:WebImageButton>
    </Template>
</igmisc:WebGroupBox>
<ig:WebScriptManager ID="WebScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ig:WebScriptManager>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Californian FB" ForeColor="Blue" style="z-index: 1; left: 676px; top: 25px; position: absolute" Text="Referral Inbox"></asp:Label>
<ig:WebHierarchicalDataSource ID="WebHierarchicalDataSource1" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 0px; top: -2px; position: absolute; height: 38px; width: 413px">
    <DataViews>
        <ig:DataView ID="LinqDataSource1Patients_DefaultView" DataMember="DefaultView" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1Patients" />
        <ig:DataView ID="LinqDataSource1UpLoad_DefaultView" DataMember="DefaultView" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1UpLoad" />
        <ig:DataView ID="LinqDataSource1Referrals_DefaultView" DataMember="DefaultView" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1Referrals" />
    </DataViews>
    <DataRelations>
        <ig:DataRelation ChildColumns="MPI" ChildDataViewID="LinqDataSource1UpLoad_DefaultView" ParentColumns="MPI" ParentDataViewID="LinqDataSource1Patients_DefaultView" />
        <ig:DataRelation ChildColumns="MPI" ChildDataViewID="LinqDataSource1Referrals_DefaultView" ParentColumns="MPI" ParentDataViewID="LinqDataSource1Patients_DefaultView" />
    </DataRelations>
</ig:WebHierarchicalDataSource>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1UpLoad" runat="server" ContextTypeName="PilotProjectV1._01.PilotProjectDBDataContext" EntityTypeName="" TableName="UpLoads">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1Referrals" runat="server" ContextTypeName="PilotProjectV1._01.PilotProjectDBDataContext" EntityTypeName="" TableName="Referrals" Where="SendingPhysicianNPI == @SendingPhysicianNPI">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="SendingPhysicianNPI" SessionField="physicianNPI" Type="Decimal" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1Patients" runat="server" ContextTypeName="PilotProjectV1._01.PilotProjectDBDataContext" EntityTypeName="" TableName="Patients">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Comment: Can u please post markup of the grid as well? Also you mean server-side RowSelectionEvent right? It fires for the parent grid, but not for the child?

Comment: Yuriy,  Thanks for the reply.  I will post the grid.

Comment: Making some progress.  The row selection event is now firing when I select the second child row.  I changed the following properties on the WebHierarchicalDataGrid.
WebHierarchicalDataGrid1 Properties -> Selection -> AutoPostBackFlags -> RowSelectionChanged -> True (it was originally false)
I also made these changes.  Not sure if they made the difference though.
Properties -> RowSelectorClientEvents -> RowSelectorClicked -> WebHierarchicalDataGrid1_Selection_RowSelectionChanged
Properties -> RowSelectorClientEvents-> RowSelectorClicking -> WebHierarchicalDataGrid1_Selection_RowSelectionChanged

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow.  How do I add comments to my post so it is easier to read?

Comment: Some stackoverflow features might not be available to you yet until you gain more reputation, but you should be able to edit and update your original post.  

Try posting full markup of your grid there e.g. everything between `<ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid` and `</ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid>`

Comment: ok, I think that is what you need.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. So by "event firing" do you mean server-side event or client-side?

Comment: Server side.  I do not know how to program java script.

Comment: Then you don't need `SelectionClientEvents` section. Also u do not need `RowSelectors` behavior. I will post an answer with possible soluition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your behavior section to

```
<Behaviors>
   <ig:Selection RowSelectType="Single" CellClickAction="Row" CellSelectType="None">
      <AutoPostBackFlags RowSelectionChanged="True" />
   </ig:Selection>
</Behaviors>
```

Just ensuring that on any click Row selection is fired

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)